# Accessing SSRS Reports outside company domain

Tags: ssrs-2008

From report manager we can assign new roles , but these users needs to be in the same network. So how to access the SSRS reports outside the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming inside your organization you are accessing directly using the URL to SSRS server? There are two ways of providing the access to the reports

- Not so good one but it works, Ask the users to dial in with their VPN
  connections and then they can continue the same way as if they were
  in same network
- Build a ASP.net application which they can log on using their
  credentials and then use Report Viewer to display the requested
  report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got to know other way like we can integrate SSRS reports with Share point and we can access our ssrs reports in outside of the network.