# Using ssrs url directly into the angular app is it a good practice?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sql-server-2016

I am using SSRS 2016, by using this we have one report. By ours.Net WEB API, how can  I communicate and render a pdf or same URL can I pass directly to my client application (angular)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the report server via url and pass the required parameters in the URL.

```
http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReportname%2fTemp&rs:Format=PDF&parameter1&yourparametervalue=<insertvaluehere>"
```

just need to play with the URL to get the correct values in.

Comment: Correct, But Can I use the same URL on my front end? if the URL  is visible anybody can play with the ID can retrieve the data .? And how can i Pass the authentication credentials ?

Comment: You can pass the link and download the PDF without exposing the URL i suppose. I've never had to pass authentication before.. so I'm not too sure on how to achieve that. .. take a look at this.. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187308/accessing-ssrs-reports-outside-company-domain

Comment: How can I achieve this, like without passing the url?